# Search data from My SQL between two dates

Tags: java, mysql, sql

When I do search between two dates in one month (for example between `02-02-2013` and `09-02-2013`)
result is showing from `03-01-2013` to `08-01-2013` and `03-02-2013` to `08-02-2013`.

Below is my code:

```
try {
    dconfig dcf=new dconfig();
    java.sql.Connection connection;
    Class.forName(dcf.driver);
    connection=(com.mysql.jdbc.Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(dcf.StrUrl,dcf.StrUid,dcf.StrPwd);
    ResultSet rs = null;
    ResultSet rscount;
    String StrQr="";

    if (jobnamesearch.getText().trim().length()>0 ) {
        StrQr=StrQr + " and job_name like '%" + jobnamesearch.getText().trim() +"%' ";
    }

    if (datetosearch.getText().trim().length()>0) {
        StrQr=StrQr + " and date > '" + datesearch.getText().toString()+"' ";
        StrQr=StrQr + " and date < '" + datetosearch.getText().toString()+"' ";
    }

    if (datesearch.getText().trim().length()>0 && datetosearch.getText().trim().length()==0) {
        StrQr=StrQr + " and date like '%" + datesearch.getText().trim().toString()+ "%' ";
    }

    if (dwsearch.getText().trim().length()>0 ) {
        StrQr=StrQr + " and dw_no like '%" + dwsearch.getText().trim() +  "%' ";
    }

    if (remsearch.getText().trim().length()>0 ) {
        StrQr=StrQr + " and rem_no like '%" + remsearch.getText().trim() +  "%' ";
    }

    if (typesearch.getSelectedItem().toString().length()<11) {
        StrQr=StrQr + " and type like '%" + typesearch.getSelectedItem().toString() +  "%' ";
    }

    if (usersearch.getSelectedItem().toString().length()>0) {
        StrQr=StrQr + " and user like '%" + usersearch.getSelectedItem().toString() +  "%' ";
    }

    java.sql.PreparedStatement stmt=connection.prepareStatement("SELECT ID,job_name,details,type,dw_no,rem_no,user,date FROM tracker  where 1=1 " + StrQr +" order by ID DESC");
    java.sql.PreparedStatement stmtcount=connection.prepareStatement("SELECT Count(*) FROM tracker  where 1=1 " + StrQr +"");
    rs = stmt.executeQuery();

    rscount = stmtcount.executeQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, I'd say it's here:

```
if (datetosearch.getText().trim().length()>0) {
    StrQr=StrQr + " and date > '" + datesearch.getText().toString()+"' ";
    StrQr=StrQr + " and date < '" + datetosearch.getText().toString()+"' ";
}
```

You're saying date > -- try changing that to >= and <=.

```
if (datetosearch.getText().trim().length()>0) {
    StrQr=StrQr + " and date >= '" + datesearch.getText().toString()+"' ";
    StrQr=StrQr + " and date <= '" + datetosearch.getText().toString()+"' ";
}
```

Also if your dates in your database are datetimes, then the <= won't work either.  You'll need to add a day to it or append 23:59 as it will be searching that day at midnight.

Hope this helps.

BTW -- this is highly vulnerable to SQL Injection.  Look into using parameterized queries instead.

Comment: I tried using >= and  <= but not working showing same results the date format in database is SS-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS

Comment: @user2011577 -- what is SS -- not familiar with that -- you're not storing the days in the datetime field?

Comment: ss means seconds i save date time in database column having datatype as VARCHAR(45) when i try to change it to datatype DATETIME it gives error as : in valid value

Comment: @user2011577 -- if you are not storing the day, then how do you want to convert it to datetime?  you need to rethink your db structure.

Comment: its DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS format i storing . is it ok if datatype is VARCHAR(45) or will it affect search... i need search query where i can get correct results in between two dates...